# Magento pull image with attribute in upsell.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I have the image attribute 'upsell_gif' applied to my gif that should be only visible in the upsell box.

When I change in the upsell.php

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(125) ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'upsell_gif')->resize(125) ?>
```

I get an error. Why? I can call the image with

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'upsell_gif')->resize(150, 150); ?>" />
```

in the view.phtml perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Uh, I got it. My attribute was set up wrong. When creating your Media attribute, select 'visible in front end' before selecting 'image'. It will disappear then and it is not editable later then.